# How to declare inner radius for input box

Tags: html, css

inner radius of input box

```
<input type="text" class="input-text">
```

css

```
.input-text{
  border-width: 4px;
  border-color: #F85534;
  padding: 6px 14px;
  width: 540px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0px !important;
  height: 35px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
  border-radius:0px;
  box-shadow: inset -1px 1px 2px 
  rgba(43, 40, 40, 0.2),-1px 1px 0px 
  rgba(43, 40, 40, 0.2),-2px 2px 0px 
  rgba(43, 40, 40, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px 1px 2px rgba(43, 40, 40, 0.2),-1px 1px 0px rgba(43, 40,40,0.2),-2px 2px 0px rgba(43, 40, 40, 0.2);
}
```

I need inner radius for text box, outer radius should be zero.

EDIT

Image [image]

Comment: not sure what you mean by *inner radius*... could you provide an example, perhaps an image or link?

Comment: The greenish bit is just a container. The radius you're seeing is just `border-radius: 3px;` (roughly) with a bit of inner shadow...

Comment: ok thank you ,so with out container ,it is not possible to do right .

Comment: You could potentially do it using the pseudo `:before` or `:after` classes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do it without wrapping the input in a div, this is how i would do it:

HTML:

```
<div class="input-wrapper"><input type="text" placeholder="text"></div>​
```

CSS:

```
.input-wrapper {
    background: blue;
    padding: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.input-wrapper input {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Check a JS-fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qCyKW/

​